# How can I reset my textbox value on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm building simple windows phone 8 application that needs integer value from user.

```
private void kredi1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        iKredi[0] = Convert.ToInt16(kredi1.Text);      
    }
```

And I have reset button that resets all values.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        iKredi[0] = 0;

        kredi1.Text = ""; // when I push this button I dont wanna see any data on the screen, thats why I used this line.
    }
```

Everything is okey but when I try to enter value again this text box, I can't do that.

How can I overcome this problem.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: The code you have provided looks OK to me, there must be something else that's causing a problem.

Comment: What exactly does "I can't do that" mean? It's not a good problem description, because it has no meaning to anyone except you.

Comment: As you have TextChangedEventArgs no reason to set zero ikredi[0] = 0 under the Button_Click_1(.....) and as @Ken White says What you can't do ? Enter another data in textbox ?  or can't puch button ?

Comment: I cant do that mean, I cant enter value same textbox. Because  iKredi[0] = Convert.ToInt16(kredi1.Text); this line trying to convert empty string to integer. What should I do to overcome this problem?

@IsmailGunes there is no problem with setting zero under the Button_Click().

Comment: @user3080888 in this case instead of putting in empty string makes it "0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a convert you should place the code of your textchanged event into a try/catch block. This should resolve the issue you are having and also prevent the error occurring if the user enters a non-int value into the text box.

```
try
{
    iKredi[0] = Convert.ToInt16(kredi1.Text);
}
catch (InvalidCastException)
{
    //handle exception here such as inform user to enter int
}
```